# Identity mismatch, bootstrap doesn't finish

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, bootstrapping, meek

Starting with the new browser bundle, I got an error with the the identities for the bridges. I'm working in a censored network, only meek was going well in the past. Now I got the following error:

```
27.10.2015 11:39:56.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27.10.2015 11:40:00.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
27.10.2015 11:40:00.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
27.10.2015 11:40:00.900 [WARN] Tried connecting to router at 0.0.2.0:2, but identity key was not as expected: wanted 4EE0CC769EB4B15A872F742EDE27D298A59DCADE but got 6DDD1DB8526282837C50E9AB5D14AB50150CD624. 
27.10.2015 11:40:00.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Unexpected identity in router certificate; IDENTITY; count 1; recommendation warn; host 4EE0CC769EB4B15A872F742EDE27D298A59DCADE at 0.0.2.0:2)
```

I've already handled it by overwriting the identity key with the received in *extension-overrides.js*.

Are there any security doubts now?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a changed configuration that the bridge operator would have done. It's unfortunate you had to deal with it, but there's a bug report about it (see https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/17473) and in your case no harm was done. Generally speaking, just updating whatever fingerprint you see is not a good idea, because it could mean that someone is impersonating your bridge and thus actively attacking you.

Newer versions of Tor Browser will have that change applied automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Same or something like this behaviour I've seen when I helped people from China to get through a censorship filter. Same logs I can periodically see here in Russia. It's a high probability of an active attacker or an ISP-wide filtership/censorship